# Take out data from a specific date in a php array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to extract data from the following array where key 3 = 2017-10-27:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 65604
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 2017-09-04 18:22:34
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 69
            [1] => 29
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 2017-10-27 07:27:59
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 70
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 2017-09-10-27:44:13
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 71
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 2017-09-05 07:52:54
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 72
            [1] => 28
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 2017-09-05 07:54:38
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 73
            [1] => 18
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 2017-09-05 07:54:53
        )
```

AS the array is too big, and contains around 20000 data. I want to pull out just the data I need. I used foreach loop but it took me too much time as I also want to update in the database

```
foreach($array as $k=>$val){
        $all = new DateTime($val[3]);
        $hun = $all->format('H:i:s');
        $date= $all->format('Y-m-d');
        $id= $val[1];
        if($date=='2017-10-27'){
             //$dbh->query("UPDATE table SET date='$date' WHERE id='$id' AND date IS NULL");
        }
}
```

Database not update, the print_r() took around 5 minutes. Any better way to filter out just the data I need.

Comment: As the date is the filter you want to use for searching in the upper array, I would recommend to make the structure of the array differently, where date is for example the key to the "main array" and the other data is followed in the "lower array".

Comment: The problem is the array comes from a device. Please can you post your proposed structure.

Comment: While you fetching these result, don't select all data just all you need is to fetch only date value from database and your stuffs resolved...

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I am not pulling the data from database, Its from bio-metric device. It gives me the array.

Comment: Is the array sorted by the timestamp? If so, you could cut your array into pieces.

Answer (score 1):

Use this function to reindex your array:

```
function reindex($arr, $commonIndex){
    $res = array(); 
    foreach( $arr as $one=>$two)
        $res[$two[$commonIndex]] = $two;
    return $res;
}
```

Usage:

```
$res = reindex($arr, 3);
echo $res['2017-10-27'];
```

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to your comment:

Example of a structure:

```
array(
    "2017-10-10" => array(  /* this date is just for filtering and structure purpose */
                    69,
                    29,
                    0,
                    "2017-10-27 07:27:59" /* optional if you still want to store the date + time in the element */
                ),
    "2017-10-10" ... etc.
)
```

Comment: I could not change the structure that comes from the device. The device utility does not support.